# How to fetch the Email form device?

Tags: android

How to fetch Email from android device like as fetch  SMS from android device  ?
any body have idea about it?
  if possible , plz give me code about it ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to access email, and [there is no standard way to "fetch SMS"](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html). Each device manufacturer has the right to replace the email and SMS clients with their own, and many device manufacturers do just that.