# How to fetch email?

Tags: android, email

According to this topic [How to fetch the Email form device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263641/how-to-fetch-the-email-form-device/4992542) there is no possibility to fetch email from email account like gmail/yahoo/hotmail, etc.
So if I wanna code an email app for android that will work with any email provider I have to setup standalone server that will be like proxy between adnroid device and email server.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question "How to fetch email from device" is not what you want.

That question is probably a bad one.  It is saying "how do I get the raw downloaded email messages from my iPhone or Android phone"? etc.

But you're saying, how do I code an android app to download from my mail server.

I suggest you look at the IMAP or POP3 protocols.
Gmail and several other web based email providers support IMAP.  Most ISP's support both POP3 and IMAP.  You'll also need to use SMTP to send email.

Note: POP3 is the easiest to code.  But has the limitation that the messages are normally downloaded from the server to your phone and will reside there.

IMAP expects you to leave the messages on the server.
This link may help you: http://namheo.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/smtps-imaps-in-java-android/
It's a java based solution.  You haven't said what language you'll be using though.

Also this one:
[Gmail (or POP3) library for Android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636960/gmail-or-pop3-library-for-android-development)

There are already email clients for Android, I'm assuming you want to roll your own or else you wouldn't be asking on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to access email. To make a universal client you need to look into POP3 and IMAP for recieving messages and sending messages is very easy through SMTP but I sounds like you need to learn how email works before writing a program that can integrate all of these.  Plus I'm positive that there are email clients for android that all ready do what your describing.  Hope this helps.